# ReactHooks 二次元配列のstateの更新による再レンダリングが行われない

Tags: reactjs

下記のようなコンポーネントで `board` という二次元配列のstateを持っており、
それをArray.mapを二回使って描画しています。

クリック時にその座標の値を変更したく、`handleClick` でstateの更新をしていますが再描画されません。
`setBoard` 前後の `console.log` では `newBoard`,`board` 共にちゃんと更新されているのですが、再描画されていないのは何故でしょうか。
また、どのように修正すべきでしょうか。

ご回答のほど、よろしくお願いします。

```tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const Test: React.FC = () => {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState<number[][]>([
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ])

  const handleClick = (row: number, col: number) => {
    if (board[row][col] === 0) {
      const newBoard = board
      newBoard[row][col] = 1
      console.log(newBoard)
      setBoard(newBoard)
      console.log(board)
    }
  }

  const items = board.map((row, rowIdx) =>
    row.map((col, colIdx) => {
      const key = `pos${rowIdx}${colIdx}`
      return (
        <div key={key} onClick={() => handleClick(rowIdx, colIdx)}>
          {col}
        </div>
      )
    }),
  )

  return (
    <div>
      {items}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handleClick` 内の `const newBoard = board` を `const newBoard = [...board]` に変えてください。

"`board`" と "`setState` に渡された `newBoard`" は同じオブジェクトなので、再描画が回避されます。`[...board]` は新しいオブジェクトを作成します。これによって `newBoard` は `board` とは別のオブジェクトになり、再描画されます。
https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

Comment: 変数名を変えただけだと再描画されないんですね...!
分かりやすく解説して下さりありがとうございました。